# Companion matrices for multivariate polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, multivariate-polynomial, companion-matrices

I am aware of companion matrices for single variable polynomials:

$$p(x) = x^k+c_{k-1}x^{k-1}+\cdots +c_0$$

$${\bf C_p} = \left[\begin{array}{ll}{\bf 0}^T & -c_0 \\ {\bf I}_{k-1} & {\bf c}_{1:k}\end{array}\right]$$

$\bf C_p$ will have the same eigenvalues as the roots of $p(x)=0$

Are there any ways to build companion matrices for multivariate polynomials (in some sense)?

---

**EDIT**
for example what I would like is that if I have $f(x,y) = (x+1)^2+(y+1)^2-1$ I can (by some recipe or algorithm) build a matrix that has the same properties in the sense of approximating roots of the polynomial when iterating matrix multiplication in the same way as one variable do.

Comment: Interesting question! For example, given a bivariate polynomial $f(x,y)$, you seek a "formula" which yields $n{\,\times\,}n$ matrices $A,B$ (for some positive integers $n$, and to be useful, you probably also want $A,B$ to commute) such that $f(A,B)=0$. Yes?

Comment: I was thinking one big matrix for both x,y simultaneously somehow, but maybe one per variable could work.

Comment: If you want just one matrix for $f(x,y)$, wouldn't the companion matrix of $f(x,x)$ work?

Comment: But how to "expand" the matrix to contain two variables?

Comment: I don't follow. Can you give a specific example?

Comment: $f(x,y) = (x+1)^2+(y+1)^2-1$ say I want to construct a matrix which has the same properties as companion matrices for 1 variable in the sense that we can iterate matrix multiplication to estimate solutions to  $f(x,y)=0$

Comment: There are two problems with this. First how do you define the characteristic polynomial of a matrix in two variables: $\det((x + y)I - A)$, $\det(xyI - A)$, something else? Second, keep in mind that $k[x,y]$ is not a PID so that structure theorem goes out the window.

Comment: What @quasi suggests with two commuting matrices seems like the most natural way to answer this question.

Comment: @quasi Feel free to write an answer based on the commuting matrices even if it's not what I had in mind.

Comment: @mathreadler: Thanks, but I don't think I added enough to warrant an answer. The interesting question relating to the two-variable idea, but which I haven't really thought about is, given a positive integer $n$ and a polynomial $f(x,y)$, how to characterize the pairs $(A,B)$ of commuting $n{\,\times\,}n$ matrices such that $f(A,B)=0$.

Comment: @mathreadler: Maybe ask a new question (once you figure out what the right question is) with a link back to this one.

Comment: Ok, I thought that maybe you had an answer but were reluctant to share in case it would not be what I hoped. @quasi yes that's what I usually try to do, make a new better question and link it.

Comment: see  https://doi.org/10.1006/jcom.1999.0530
Multivariate Polynomials, Duality, and Structured Matrices
They have some examples you are interested

Comment: @mkatkov Thank you. Wow it's very big, but I will try to read it. Do you happen to know how to make a matrix according to the article for the circle equation example?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1630316/339790

Comment: One interesting property of companion matrices is that they are invariant under permutations. I like to think of them as building blocks for a canonical form (the Frobenius normal form, which is also called the rational normal form) under matrix conjugation. However, you seem to be interested in them from another point of view.

Comment: @Malkoun Aha. I have not considered this. It could be interesting. I am originally an electrical engineer and mostly try to find uses for mathematical things which I learn about in practical computational contexts for algorithms in various fields. I have heard about Frobenius form, but I have not investigated it so much. Thank you for the idea!